# No connection with Ethernet

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, ethernet

When I installed ubuntu 14.04 my ethernet is not connecting.
Anyone can help me , please ?

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0

  Type:              Wired

  Driver:            r8169

  State:             unavailable

  Default:           no

  HW Address:        00:24:1D:13:3D:08

  Capabilities:

  Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
  Carrier:         off

Comment: Try doing this test `sudo dhclient -r eth0` and `sudo dhclient eth0` and finally `ping -c2 8.8.8.8`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the line disconnected, but it probably isn't. You probably have 2 ethernet ports and you plugged it in the extendible PCI ports, not the builtin motherboard. I don't think Ubuntu lets you configure your network cards manually. You must have to plugin to the motherboard port and reinstall.